# How do i convert my x, y, z rotations into axis-angle to calculate a quaternion

Tags: java, math, quaternions

//see new (rollMode==2) below (with inverse())

//You guys look like you are familiar with Quaternions and 3D input.  I read and read and can't translate what people say into code.  I'm trying to make a virtual solar system with planets and spaceships for fun.  (I started 35 years ago on a Applet II plus but, nobody had created a 3D lib with multiple views and I don't have the math skills to write all that myself).
    Pairing things down, I need to know how to get the input data to make Axis/Angle and/or Quaternions work to turn and drive my ship.
EDIT: I found the formulas (and put it all here for people in the future) but, I don't get good rotation - just change of heading (no cool spin while looking at something).
EDIT: I simplified things. My roll still comes out in the wrong axis.

```
//initial setup
Q1 = new Quat4d();//initial rotation
Q1.inverse();
Q1.conjugate();
//setup input
//set up Q2 (quaternion) with new rotation increment (delta)
//d is (x meters/sec) / frames per second
A2 = new AxisAngle3d(Math.toRadians(d.x), Math.toRadians(d.y), Math.toRadians(d.z));
Q2 = new Quat4d();
Q2.set(A2);//set quaternion with axis/angle
Q2.inverse();//local frame of reference
//Q2.conjugate();//local frame of reference
Q1.mul(Q2);//update with new rotation increment
```

Comment: So, are you looking for a 3D lib, now that there are plenty (off-topic), or do you still want to create your own?

Comment: I'm using Java3D.  It has all the objects but, the documentation on how to use the objects is virtually nonexistent.  FYI (and I forgot to comment on that with the post, It seems to have the Y axis as the vertical (solar polar north/south) axis. (If you have your right hand in front of you and pointing to your left, your fingers point to the positive directions of the axes.)  I also created the AxisVector3d that can flip the y and z so it can be used with other libs.

Comment: Here are some links that are better then the cpprogramming link (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html). http://physicsforgames.blogspot.com/2010/02/quaternions.html?m=1 and http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/ and http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut08%20Quaternions.html

Comment: I found the conversions from euler to axis/angle and from euler to Quaternions.  I don't get the roll I want. it seems like the objects are rolling on the z axis, not around my ship axis.  I set Q2 to Vector3d(0d, 0d, 0.01d) then Q1.mul(Q2). set my transform3d to Q1 and set my location then save it to the transformGroup.

Comment: Maybe this isn't as hard for you as it is for me.  I only find discussion about rotations and bits of code for rotations but not both together.  I found something about using local frame of reference for 1st person rotations using inverse().  I think i set up Q1 ok and .inverse() it.  what would i set tempRotVel to? and should the below work?